# How to get the index of a loop in Applescript?

Tags: list, loops, applescript

I have a list of different length strings that I'm looping:

```
set my_list to {"abc", "defg", "hi", "jklmno"}

repeat with the_item in my_list
    -- get index of the_item
end repeat
```

How can I find the index of the_item while I'm looping?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can either introduce a counter and update it with each iteration through the loop:

```
set counter to 0
repeat with the_item in my_list
  set counter to counter + 1
  -- do stuff
end repeat
```

or use a [different loop form](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128207):

```
repeat with n from 1 to count of my_list
  -- do stuff with (item n of my_list)
end repeat
```

Comment: Broken link? Redirects to Apple support.